# Сортировка строки по алфавиту

Tags: php, сортировка

Подскажите, почему не работает такой код?

```
$string = "gfedcba";

for($i=0; $i<count($string); $i++){
    for($j=$i+1; $j<count($string); $j++){
        if($string[$i]>$string[$j]){
            $temp = $string[$j];
            $string[$j] = $string[$i];
            $string[$i] = $temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Насколько я знаю, строка уже является массивом. Но почему-то данный вариант кода не работает правильно. Нужно всё равно разбивать строку на массив с помощью `str_split`. Не подскажите почему так?

Answer (score 1):

Оно то работать будет, только с однобайтовыми кодировками и `str_split` тоже.
Так-как, перемещение по `$str[3]` индексам символов строки - небезопасно в многобайтовой кодировке.

```
function str_sort($str) {
    $arr = array();
    for ($i = 0, $len = strlen($str); $i < $len; ++$i) {
        $arr[] = $str{$i};
    }
    sort($arr);
    return join($arr);
}
$string = "gfedcba";
echo str_sort($string); // abcdefg
```

Для работы с `unicode`, потребуется что-то типа такого:

```
function str_sort($string) {
    mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');
    $arr = array();
    while ($strlen = mb_strlen($string)) {
        $arr[] = mb_substr($string, 0, 1);
        $string = mb_substr($string, 1, $strlen);
    }
    sort($arr);
    return join($arr);
}
$string = "дгвба";
echo str_sort($string); //абвгд
```