# PHP Символы на русском языке

Tags: php

Вообщем народ самая обычная проблема "наверно".
Есть функция:

```
class PHPWorks {
    public function sort_string($line) {
        $array_line = explode(" ", $line);
        $new_line = '';

        foreach ($array_line as $a_line) {
            $line_one = str_split(strtolower($a_line));
            sort($line_one);
            $ret = "";
            foreach($line_one as $line_o) {
                $ret .= $line_o;
            }

            $new_line .= $ret . " ";
        }

        return trim($new_line);
    }
}
```

Функция работает, но проблема в том, что если я отправляю символы на русском языке, то они выводятся в виде ромбиков с вопросами как это исправить??

Comment: а вы указывали нужную кодировку? в html либо в php файле?

Comment: Ну это как посмотреть у меня есть 3 строки которые я прогоняю через эту функцию 'lemon orange banana apple', 'лимон апельсин банан яблоко', 'αβγαβγ αβγαβγαβγ' если ставить кодировку utf-8 работает только 1 строка, если ставим кодировку windows-1251, работает 1 и 2 строка, а вот 3 не хочет работать ((

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сортировка строки по алфавиту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/843046/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%83)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем полностью рабочий код который поддерживает и русский, вдруг кому-то пригодится:

```
class PHPWorks {
    public function sort_string($line) {
        $array_line = mb_split("\s", $line);
        $new_line = '';

        foreach ($array_line as $a_line) {
            $line_one = preg_split('//u', strtolower($a_line), null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
            sort($line_one);
            $ret = '';
            foreach($line_one as $line_o) {
                $ret .= $line_o;
            }

            $new_line .= $ret . ' ';
        }
        return trim($new_line);
    }
}
```

Comment: `strtolower` не работает с русскими буквами, для этого есть `mb_strtolower`.

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь для строки в многобайтовой кодировке использовать функцию `explode`. Данная функция работает побайтово и "портит" символы многобайтовых кодировок. Для русского языка лучше использовать:

```
$array_line = mb_split("\s", $line);
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-split.php

Comment: Ну и вообще при использовании других языков желательно пользоваться функциями `mb_*`

Comment: Это конечно хорошо, только как оказалось портила не только `explode`, но как оказалось и `str_split`